# Creating date array from cell array of strings

Tags: matlab, text-processing, cell-array

I have a cell array of strings the first few elements of which look like:

```
'140322P00024000'
'140324PR0025000'
'140325P00Q26000'
```

where `'140322'` refers to 2014-03-22 (22nd march, 2014). I want to obtain the following array from the above:

```
735680
735682
735683
```

Please note in the given array only the first 6 letters are consistent and they refer to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first six characters can be converted with [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) directly using the format `'yymmdd'`:

```
>> d = datenum('140322','yymmdd')
d =
      735680
>> datestr(d)
ans =
22-Mar-2014
```

Do them all with [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html):

```
>> cellfun(@(x)datenum(x(1:6),'yymmdd'),C)
ans =
      735680
      735682
      735683
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateString = '19-May-2001';
formatIn = 'dd-mmm-yyyy';
datenum(DateString,formatIn)
```

Taken from:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html

Converting to the 'DD-MM-YYYY' string should be straightforward:

```
currentLine = cellArray{y,x};
DateString = [currentLine[3:4] '-' currentLine[5:6] '-20' currentLine[1:2]];
```

Hope this helps.